# Why am i getting ELIF Invalid Syntax?

Tags: python

I cant see anything wrong with the following code :

```
    elif choice == "2":
    while True:
        PhoneSearch = raw_input("What is their telephone number? : ")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Telephone = (?)",(PhoneSearch,))
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row:
            CustID = row[0]
            print "|------------------------------------------|"
            print "|Customer ID : " , row[0]
            print "|Forename : " , row[1]
            print "|Surname : " , row[2]
            print "|Address Line 1 : " , row[3]
            print "|Address Line 2 : " , row[4]
            print "|City : " , row[5]
            print "|Postcode : " , row[6]
            print "|Telephone number : " , row[7]
            print "|E-Mail : " , row[8]
            while True:
                print '|Do you want to see what seats', row[1]
                choice = raw_input("|Choice Y/N:")
                if choice == 'Y':
                    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE CustID = (?)", (CustID,))
                    rowseat = cur.fetchone()
                    if rowseat: # or if rowseat is not None, etc.
                        print "|Seats booked:" , rowseat[0]
                        print "|------------------------------------------|"
                        break
                    else:
                        print("database doesn't have correct info")
            else:
                print("Na")
```

Yet i get a syntax error on the Elif statement at the top. Please tell me why this is happening or where the error is?

Comment: Is your code actually indented like this (the `elif` lined up with the `while`)? If so, that's a problem. Also, you have an `if` before this and aren't just starting with an `elif`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Python expects an indented block after your `elif` statement, same as for an `if`, `while` or `else` statement. In your example, everything after `elif` should be indented.

Comment: Everything is lined up, infact the if statement above it which is if == "1" is the exact copy of this one, yet it still gives an invalid syntax

Comment: In which case, are you sure you haven't made a mistake earlier in your script (e.g. not closed brackets after a function call)?