# Elif is invalid?

Tags: python, sqlite

This code:

```
def viewdetails():
    os.system('cls')
    print "|__________________________________________|"
    print "|----------------View Details--------------|"
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    print "|1 - Search with Customer ID               |"
    print "|2 - Search with Telephone number          |"
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    choice = raw_input("|Choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        while True:
            IDSearch = raw_input("|What is their ID? : ")
            conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustID = (?)",(IDSearch,))
            row = cur.fetchone()
            if row[0] != IDSearch:
                print "|------------------------------------------|"
                print "|          Invalid ID, Try again!          |"
                print "|------------------------------------------|"
            else:
                break
        CustID = row[0]
        print "|------------------------------------------|"
        print "|Customer ID : " , row[0]
        print "|Forename : " , row[1]
        print "|Surname : " , row[2]
        print "|Address Line 1 : " , row[3]
        print "|Address Line 2 : " , row[4]
        print "|City : " , row[5]
        print "|Postcode : " , row[6]
        print "|Telephone number : " , row[7]
        print "|E-Mail : " , row[8]
        while True:
            print '|Do you want to see what seats', row[1], 'has booked?|'
            choice = raw_input("|Y/N: ")
            if choice == 'Y':
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE CustID = (?)", (CustID,))
                rowseat = cur.fetchone()
                if rowseat:
                    print "|Seats booked:" , rowseat[0]
                    print "|------------------------------------------|"
                    break
                else:
                    print "|" , row[1] , "Hasnt booked any seats."
                    break
    print(" ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    print("|Please select an option:                  |")
    print("|1 - Return to menu                        |")
    print("|2 - Book seats                            |")
    print("|3 - Edit details                          |")
    choice = raw_input("|Please put choice here : ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    elif choice == "2":
        while True:
            IDSearch = raw_input("|What is their ID? : ")
            conn = sqlite3.connect('SADS.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustID = (?)",(IDSearch,))
            row = cur.fetchone()
            if row[0] != IDSearch:
                print "|------------------------------------------|"
                print "|          Invalid ID, Try again!          |"
                print "|------------------------------------------|"
            else:
                break
        CustID = row[0]
        print "|------------------------------------------|"
        print "|Customer ID : " , row[0]
        print "|Forename : " , row[1]
        print "|Surname : " , row[2]
        print "|Address Line 1 : " , row[3]
        print "|Address Line 2 : " , row[4]
        print "|City : " , row[5]
        print "|Postcode : " , row[6]
        print "|Telephone number : " , row[7]
        print "|E-Mail : " , row[8]
        while True:
            print '|Do you want to see what seats', row[1], 'has booked?|'
            choice = raw_input("|Y/N: ")
            if choice == 'Y':
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE CustID = (?)", (CustID,))
                rowseat = cur.fetchone()
                if rowseat:
                    print "|Seats booked:" , rowseat[0]
                    print "|------------------------------------------|"
                    break
                else:
                    print "|" , row[1] , "Hasnt booked any seats."
                    break
    print(" ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    print("|Please select an option:                  |")
    print("|1 - Return to menu                        |")
    print("|2 - Book seats                            |")
    print("|3 - Edit details                          |")
    choice = raw_input("|Please put choice here : ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    print(" ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    print("|Please select an option:                  |")
    print("|1 - Return to menu                        |")
    print("|2 - Book seats                            |")
    print("|3 - Edit details                          |")
    choice = raw_input("|Please put choice here : ")
    print "|------------------------------------------|"
    if choice == "1":
        mainprogram()
    elif choice == "2":
        availablity()
    elif choice == "3":
        editdetails()
    os.system('cls')

viewdetails()
```

( http://pastebin.com/X62jRLiL )

Is getting the elif statement `elif choice == "2":` is an invalid syntax apparently, yet the `elif choice == "1":` works and the code following is an exact replica of one another?

Comment: This is not a good way to program, Charlie. Take a step back and think about each statement, and do not copy-paste.

Comment: they were completely different sections of code, so i backed it up. Then copy and pasted, and it still didnt work

Comment: Well, look at the indentation of these two consecutive lines: `print "|------------------------------------------|"` and `elif choice == "2":`. Notice anything?

Comment: You need to indent the lines between `if choice == "1":` and  `elif choice == "2":`. There are some stray `print` statements

Comment: Oh right, thank you. Sorry for sounding really new...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992447/why-am-i-getting-elif-invalid-syntax

Comment: @init3 yes i gather that, i was confused still alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python code needs to be indented properly.

Otherwise, it is invalid.

It's probably the first thing you learn about python (so grab a book, such as "Thinking in Python"); and at the same time, the most critizized thing (at least by non-users).

Valid code example:

```
if a == "1":
    echo "Apples"
elif b == "2":
    echo "Bananas"
```

invalid code due to **indentation errors**:

```
if a == "1":
echo "Apples"
elif b == "2":
    echo "Bananas"
```

Comment: But it is indented properly?

Comment: No it is not indented properly.

Comment: @CharlieSay there is no indentation *before* the `elif` where the error is reported.

Comment: Thank you, i am sorry for not noticing.

Comment: Note tha there is not actually an `echo` command in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing tabs and spaces, don't do that. Run your script with as:

```
python -tt yourscript.py
```

to find where. Replace all tabs with spaces, configure your editor to only use spaces for indentation.

Comment: May I ask why isn't this a comment? I believe that replacing tabs with spaces won't help if he still doesn't understand the basic need of the proper indentation which was the problem

Comment: @Alexander I do understand indentation, just i didnt notice that one somehow.

Comment: @Alexander: it is not indented properly *in this post* because Stack Overflow displays tabs as 4 spaces wide, or people try to replace the tabs with spaces here. If the OP has an editor that uses 8 spaces per indentation then the indentation will *look* correct.

Comment: @CharlieSay, fair enough